# Arduino read input pin 1 to 6 (BIN to BCD) and show value on Arduino TFT display

Tags: arduino

How do I read pin 1-6 and show the value on Arduino TFT display. (BIN to BCD)

```
Ex: pin 5,4,3,2,1,0 all = 1 (111111) will show the value on display: 63
Ex: pin 5,4,3,2,1,0 (100000) will show the value on display: 32
Ex: pin 5,4,3,2,1,0 all = 0 (000000) will show the value on display: 00
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

```
  int result = 0;  
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    if (digitalRead (i + 1) == HIGH)
      result |= bit (i);

  if (result < 10)
    Serial.print ("0");
  Serial.println (result);
```

That "ors" in each bit from pins 1 to 6. I used a Serial print there because you didn't give any indication what sort of TFT display you have*, but the principle will be the same.

---

* Other than being an Arduino one. :)

Comment: I use Arduino Graphic TFT LCD Screen 1,77"

Comment: Just a comment: if the pins belong to the same port (e.g. pins 0-5 are on PORTD) you can use the port manipulation instead of reading every pin one by one. And as for the screen, this is the most difficult part. If it is supported, search for UTFT library and try to use it with your screen to print chars. Otherwise read the datasheet of your controller and learn how to send data to it, then write your own functions..